# How to use the CPU window for debugging in D7

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-7

I have an unknown issue that causes the CPU window to appear. I have traced in the source to localize the problem to a call to MMSYSTEM:

```
FError := midioutClose(FMidiHandle); 

function midiOutClose; external mmsyst name 'midiOutClose';
```

I have never become proficient with the CPU debugger. There are no symbols, and I have no way of knowing what it is telling me.

Can anybody point me to a tutorial on how to use the CPU window of the debugger to find this sort of problem?

Comment: There's no way to debug into WinAPI code using the Delphi debugger, even with symbols. You need to use the code Windows debugger (WinDbg - sorry, no link handy), available from Microsoft, set up to use the Windows debugging symbols. However, this is probably not necessary - chances of it being an actual bug in the API are very slim. It's hard to help you figure out where the problem might be, though; you didn't post any error message, and only posted one line of actual code with no context. (The second line is just an external linkage to the `MMSYSTEM` DLL function.)

Comment: You do not need to debug Windows API unless you suspect a bug in one of its function (which is unlikely). You might want to use `midiOutGetErrorText` to retreve the error description. The MIDI output buffer is probaly still being played when you called `midiOutClose`. Meaning that the playback on that buffer hasn't finished.

Comment: Yeah, you need to show some code and give details of what errors you see.

Comment: @ken You can debug into Win API code in the Delphi debugger. It's not terribly productive there being no source code. You don't do any better with WinDbg though, still no source.

Comment: @Jay I think an exception is being raised which means that the api call does not return properly and there's no opportunity to call the error function.

Comment: @David, I agree. `WinDpg` is actually better, although you're still stuck with working in ASM and interpreting register content and stack traces. The point was, though, in the largest part of my comment - there's very seldom a need to debug the API itself, as problems are almost always in your own code.

Comment: When an exception occurred in system DLLs, in most cases, it was caused by corrupted memory data before the function is called. The corruption can be caused by data offset/size miscalculation, buffer overflow, or unsafe thread access.

Comment: Another possible cause is that floating point exceptions are unmasked, but Windows code is written assuming that they are masked.

Comment: @tim Can I ask why you have asked this question but are ignoring our requests for more information? If you are not interested in this anymore then please delete the question. If you are interested then please take the time to supply more details.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was away from this project for a while. I do appreciate your comments. @David, correct: it didn't get to the point of returning with an error - it happens inside the mmsystem call.

Comment: @Jay, I only use MIDI for Sysex, so "buffer playing" is not relevant, but your comment got me thinking. The failure is not 100%, so it points to a timing problem. The error occurs only if I'm using an interface that is actually USB-based.  Traditional MIDI ports never get the exception. So I put in sleep(100) right before the call, and I have not seen the CPU windows since then.

Comment: @tim11g I fully understand that the function does not return. However, the debugger will show an error dialog describing the exception that has been raised. What does that say?

Comment: I took out the Sleep statements and ran it again until I got a failure. Within the D7 IDE, I only get a CPU window, and no message. http://i.imgur.com/IvYO0.png I couldn't get it to fail outside the IDE.