# How to look at compiled Delphi Code?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction

I'm wondering how can I look at the compiler-generated code in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE, like someone answers in this post:

[What is the better way to check for an empty string in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619801/what-is-the-better-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-delphi/10620303#10620303)

Comment: not sure i understand your question? or how an empty string has anything to do with it

Comment: I just want to look at the compiler-instructions, that my code produces and an answer to the question in the link shows his compiler-generated code and i was wondering how to do this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what the [CPU window](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/CPU_Windows_Index) is for. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the source code that you want to investigate, then when the program is halted press `Ctrl-Alt-C` to open the main CPU window (or any of the other shortcuts mentioned under the IDE menu View / Debug Windows / CPU Windows).

See also [How to use the CPU window for debugging in D7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705155/how-to-use-the-cpu-window-for-debugging-in-d7)

Comment: ... or `Alt-F2` shortcut. :)

Answer (score 6):

during debugging session go MainMenu -> view -> debug windows -> CPU -> Full CPU Panel

Answer (score -3):

There is also something called codesite,  it will let you trace , time , and a ton of other things  http://www.raize.com/DevTools/codesite/

Comment: This is not related to the question. I think you misunderstood what was being asked.